# What does rampUsersPerSec function really do?

Tags: gatling

I find Gatling documentation a bit unclear about a specific function: `rampUsersPerSec`.

> Injects a random number of users per second over a given duration
>   (rate1) to (rate2) during(dur unit)
>
> Injects users from starting rate1
>   to target rate2, defined in users per second, during a given duration.
>   Eg : rampUsersPerSec(10) to(20) during(10 minutes)

For instance, with `rampUsersPerSec(1) to 100 during 10`, I may have 41 more users on second 1, then 99 more users on second 2, then 8 more users on second 3, etc.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`rampUsersPerSec` is virtual user injection scheme in an open workload model: you define the arrival rate of new virtual users. Number of concurrent users inside the system is a consequence of the simulation scenario and service response times.