# Gatling: Understanding rampUsersPerSec(minTPS) to maxTPS during seconds

Tags: scala, gatling

I am checking a scala code for gatling where they inject transactions for the period of 20 seconds.

```
/*TPS = Transaction Per Second */   
  val minTps = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("minTps", "1"))
  val maxTps = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("maxTps", "5"))

  var rampUsersDurationInMinutes =Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("rampUsersDurationInMinutes", "20"))
  setUp(scn.inject(
    rampUsersPerSec(minTps) to maxTps during (rampUsersDurationInMinutes seconds)).protocols(tcilProtocol))
```

---

The same question was asked [What does rampUsersPerSec function really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51739593/what-does-rampuserspersec-function-really-do) but never answered. I think that ***ideally*** the the graph should be looking like that.

> could you please confirm if I correctly understood
>   **rampUsersPerSec**?

[image]

- block (ramp) 1 = 4 users  +1
- block (ramp) 2 = 12 users +2
- block (ramp) 3 = 24 users +3
- block (ramp) 4 = 40 users +4
- block (ramp) 5 = 60 users +5

The results show that the requests count is indeed 60. Is my calculation correct?

```
---- Global Information --------------------------------------------------------
> request count                                         60 (OK=38     KO=22    )
> min response time                                   2569 (OK=2569   KO=60080 )
> max response time                                  61980 (OK=61980  KO=61770 )
> mean response time                                 42888 (OK=32411  KO=60985 )
> std deviation                                      20365 (OK=18850  KO=505   )
> response time 50th percentile                      51666 (OK=32143  KO=61026 )
> response time 75th percentile                      60903 (OK=48508  KO=61371 )
> response time 95th percentile                      61775 (OK=61886  KO=61725 )
> response time 99th percentile                      61974 (OK=61976  KO=61762 )
> mean requests/sec                                  0.741 (OK=0.469  KO=0.272 )
---- Response Time Distribution ------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

rampUsersPerSec is an open workload model injection where you specify the rate at which users start the scenario. The [gatling documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/3.1/general/simulation_setup/) says that this injection profile

> Injects users from starting rate to target rate, defined in users per second, during a given duration. Users will be injected at regular intervals

So while I'm not sure that the example you provide is precisely correct in that gatling is using a second as the 'regular interval' (it might be a smoother model), you are more or less correct. You specify a starting rate and a final rate, and gatling works out all the intermediate injection rates for your duration.

Note that this says nothing about the number of concurrent users your simulation will generate - that is a function of the arrival rate (which you control) and the execution time (which you do not)

Comment: James Warr


So we want to increase (**ramp up**) the number of TPS from **1** to **5** in **20** seconds.  How gatling does it **we cannot control it**.  So basically my first chart is wrong. As you correctly mentioned it **might be a smoother model**

Comment: In the second graph why do we have these sudden fluctuations in the graph? that's like gatling is trying to ramp up then goes down then up then down?

Comment: What if we don't reach the needed ramp up in the limit that we defined earlier? in our case 20 seconds

Comment: part of this will depend on the nature of your scenario. When you define an injection profile, you're specifying users *not* requests. Depending on what requests you have in a scenario, and how long they take to execute, your RPS might vary significantly from your active users. Are you able to share the scenario definition you're using?